# Date regex python

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to match dates in a string where the date is formatted as (month dd, yyyy). I am confused by what I see when I use my regex pattern below. It only matches strings that begin with a date. What am I missing?

```
 >>> p = re.compile('[A-z]{3}\s{1,}\d{1,2}[,]\s{1,}\d{4}')
 >>> s = "xyz Dec 31, 2013 - Jan 4, 2014"
 >>> print p.match(s).start()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'

 >>> s = "Dec 31, 2013 - Jan 4, 2014"
 >>> print p.match(s).start()
 0 #Correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the search method instead of match. Match compares the whole string but search finds the matching part.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#finding-all-adverbs) rather than [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#search-vs-match), it will return to you list of all matches:

```
>>> s = "Dec 31, 2013 - Jan 4, 2014"
>>> r = re.findall(r'[A-z]{3}\s{1,}\d{1,2}[,]\s{1,}\d{4}',s)
>>> r
['Dec 31, 2013', 'Jan 4, 2014']
>>>
>>> s = 'xyz Dec 31, 2013 - Jan 4, 2014'
>>> r = re.findall(r'[A-z]{3}\s{1,}\d{1,2}[,]\s{1,}\d{4}',s)
>>> r
['Dec 31, 2013', 'Jan 4, 2014']
```

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#):

> `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)` If zero or more characters **at the
>   beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a
>   corresponding MatchObject instance

In the other hand:

> `findall()` matches all occurrences of a pattern, not just the first one
>   as search() does.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = re.compile(r'.*?[A-Za-z]{3}\s{1,}\d{1,2}[,]\s{1,}\d{4}')
```

`match` matches a string from start.if start does is not same it will fail.In the first example `xyz` will be consumed by `[A-Za-z]{3}` but rest of the string will not match.

You can directly use your regex with `re.findall` and get the result without caring about the location of the match.