# Reading this date using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am currently reading a GMail message. I am parsing data from this message for the back-end of a mail app I am writing in Tkinter. I am still a noob at python and have not been able to wrap my head around solving regex problems very well. 
I am trying to parse the date that Google gives me, formatted as: Fri, 07 Dec 2018 00:35:24 -0800 (PST) What would be the appropriate Python regex syntax to search for this?

`print(email_date)`

`12/07/18 00:35`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958198/date-regex-python)

Answer (score 1):

One way this could be done is to first parse the date into a usable format, and then use the `datetime` module to convert it to the format you want:

```
import re
import datetime

parsed_date = re.findall("(\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})", email_date)[0]
formatted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(parsed_date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

**Example**

```
>>> email_date = "Fri, 07 Dec 2018 00:35:24 -0800 (PST)"
...
>>> print(formatted_date)
 '12/07/18 00:35'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer seems fine.  Something to get you started (this prints all the numbers parsed from numerical data:

```
import re

date_str="12/07/18 00:33"
m = re.findall('\d+', date_str)
for e in m:
  print e
```

Comment: What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use `.{3},.{28}\(.{3}\)` and [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html), i.e.:

```
import re, dateutil.parser
for d in re.findall(r".{3},.{28}\(.{3}\)", your_string):
    print(dateutil.parser.parse(d).strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

---

**Output:**

```
12/07/18 00:35
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lgra74/2)

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/RP0)